# Create a row for every month between 2 dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, date-range, generate-series

I need to create a row for every month (result should be first day of the month) between 2 dates for each person in my table. For example, if I have the following data in my source table:

```
rowID | person      | startdate   | enddate
1     | 12345       | 2014-04-01  | 2014-11-30
2     | 67890       | 2014-03-01  | 2014-05-01
```

I want the results in my destination table to be:

```
person | month
12345  | 2014-04-01
12345  | 2014-05-01
12345  | 2014-06-01
12345  | 2014-07-01
12345  | 2014-08-01
12345  | 2014-09-01
12345  | 2014-10-01
12345  | 2014-11-01
67890  | 2014-03-01
67890  | 2014-04-01
67890  | 2014-05-01
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need for a CTE or a lateral join:

```
select
    person,
    generate_series(
        date_trunc('month', startdate), 
        enddate, '1 month'
    )::date as month
from rfem
order by 1, 2
;
 person |   month    
--------+------------
  12345 | 2014-04-01
  12345 | 2014-05-01
  12345 | 2014-06-01
  12345 | 2014-07-01
  12345 | 2014-08-01
  12345 | 2014-09-01
  12345 | 2014-10-01
  12345 | 2014-11-01
  67890 | 2014-03-01
  67890 | 2014-04-01
  67890 | 2014-05-01
```

Comment: Using a set returning function in the `select` list is discouraged. So there **is** indeed a need for a lateral join.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That discouragement is intended for multiple set returning functions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you give a reason why a set returning function in the select list is discouraged?  Or a link that explains it?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate minimum and maximum dates for each person with first days of months then generate monthly-based ranges between those dates using `generate_series`:

```
WITH date_ranges AS (
SELECT 
  person,
  min(date_trunc('month', startdate))::timestamptz AS min_start,
  max(date_trunc('month', enddate))::timestamptz AS max_end
FROM person_table
GROUP BY 1
)
SELECT 
  dr.person,
  ser.month::DATE as month
FROM date_ranges AS dr,
     generate_series(min_start, max_end, '1 month') AS ser(month)
```

**Output**

```
 person |   month
--------+------------
  12345 | 2014-04-01
  12345 | 2014-05-01
  12345 | 2014-06-01
  12345 | 2014-07-01
  12345 | 2014-08-01
  12345 | 2014-09-01
  12345 | 2014-10-01
  12345 | 2014-11-01
  67890 | 2014-03-01
  67890 | 2014-04-01
  67890 | 2014-05-01
```

How it works? Implicit `LATERAL JOIN` for function call forces the calculation for every row from the input.

This solution takes into account that you may have more than 1 row per each person with dates and it takes the highest possible range there is.